# Как разместить виртуальный сервера с доменом и без домена nginx

Tags: nginx

У меня есть два проекта фронт и бек. На фронте spa приложение, а на беке json api.

Оба проекта находятся на одном хосте. **Http server - nginx**  Моя конфигурация **nginx** выглядит так

```js
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
          

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/gateway_error.log  debug;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  600;


    server {


        listen 80;

        server_name _ ; 
            
        root /var/www/project/public;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        charset utf-8;

        server_tokens off;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    server  {
        listen 80;
        server_name front.com

        root /var/www/front/public;

        index index.html index.htm;

        charset utf-8;

        server_tokens off;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }


}
```

когда я делаю запрос на **front.com** мне возвращается данные с моего api (потому что он находит ip и вызывает этот проект)

Вопрос можно ли сделать так что бы и фронт (с доменом) и бек (без домена, просто с ip адресом) работали корректно. Когда я делаю запрос на front.com то мне отсылается фронт,  а когда просто по ip то вызывался бекенд. Или нужно также домен для бекенда?

Спасибо огромное за оказанное внимание!

Comment: Можно конечно, просто вместо домена используйте ip и всё

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за ответ! Для этого я сделал **server_name _** но к сожалению тогда сервер с **front.com** не работает :c

Comment: Команда `nginx -t` пишет какие-нибудь предупреждения?

Comment: нет всё успешно. Я также менял расположениями виртуальные сервера и тогда если я обращаюсь по ip то он открывает фронт

Comment: А вы уверены что делаете запрос именно на front.com, а не на www.front.com или что-нибудь ещё похожее?

Comment: @andreymal да уверен. Мне ломает голову эта ошибка :)

Comment: У вас `nginx -t` точно-точно не пишет никаких предупреждений? Я скопировал ваш конфиг себе и у меня он пишет `server name "/var/www/front/public" has suspicious symbols` как бы намекая на забытую точку с запятой

Comment: да точно)) этот конфиг "муляж" ситуации у меня на проекте потому что по соображениям безопасности мне не хочется публиковать настоящие конфиги

Comment: Этот «муляж» не позволяет воспроизвести проблему (когда я ставлю точку с запятой, у меня запросы уходят во front.com как положено), так что и помочь тоже не получится

Comment: @andreymal Да вы были правы. Хоть и синтаксической ошибки не было, но я слепой крот сделал опечатку в домене (вместо r написал t) спасибо еще раз! Хорошего вечера